# In Java(Kotlin) If kafka topic created programmatically without specifying bootstrap-server option, is it created by default on localhost:9092?

Tags: java, kotlin, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I need to programmatically set up topics creation on different bootstrap servers. Currently all created topics are on localhost:9092. In current app config, I can't find any indication of setting this param. I found examples that indicate that you can indeed create topic without specifying bootstrap server option, like here

```
@Bean
  public NewTopic topicExample() {
    return TopicBuilder.name("my-first-kafka-topic")
      .partitions(6)
      .replicas(3)
      .build();
  }
```

My questions:
are topics indeed are created on localhost:9092 by default?
How can I specify port on which I want topic to be created?

Answer (score 1):

The spring topic beans use the AdminClient to create the topics

You still need to define the bootstrap-server for AdminClient with `spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers`, and yes, it defaults to localhost:9092